# Git processes living on a linux server

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, ssh

So I have access to my shared hosting server via SSH. The hosting company warned me about too much resource consuming. When I logged to the server and run `top` to view the resource usage information on the Linux shared hosting server I get the following log:

```
top - 09:31:20 up 4 days, 19:59,  5 users,  load average: 8.30, 8.84, 9.30
Tasks:  39 total,   1 running,  38 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 26.8%us,  4.0%sy,  1.1%ni, 64.9%id,  2.9%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65709912k total, 63435736k used,  2274176k free,  6961904k buffers
top - 09:38:42 up 4 days, 20:07,  5 users,  load average: 7.06, 8.13, 8.81
Tasks:  40 total,   1 running,  39 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 16.8%us,  3.4%sy,  0.2%ni, 77.7%id,  1.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65709912k total, 64754844k used,   955068k free,  7025016k buffers
Swap:  4190204k total,  1044576k used,  3145628k free, 43596764k cached
```

And this is the table with processes:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

 81448 my_username  20   0  105m 1920 1504 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 bash                                                                                                                                       
 107642 my_username  20   0 11708 1800 1388 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash                                                                                                                                       
 232879 my_username  20   0  105m 1200 1196 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash                                                                                                                                       
 232892 my_username  20   0 11804  508  504 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 232895 my_username  20   0  105m 1236 1232 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-pull                                                                                                                                   
 232911 my_username  20   0 11808  616  612 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 232912 my_username  20   0 76316 1980 1972 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-remote-http                                                                                                                            
 389588 my_username  20   0 15048 1216  972 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.33 top                                                                                                                                        
 391829 my_username  20   0  105m 1912 1504 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 bash                                                                                                                                       
 693783 my_username  20   0  105m 1216 1212 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash                                                                                                                                       
 693792 my_username  20   0 11804  508  504 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 693793 my_username  20   0  105m 1280 1248 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-pull                                                                                                                                   
 693809 my_username  20   0 11808  732  612 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 693810 my_username  20   0 76316 2832 1972 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-remote-http                                                                                                                            
 724630 my_username  20   0  105m 1216 1212 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash                                                                                                                                       
 724639 my_username  20   0 11804  508  504 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 724642 my_username  20   0  105m 1252 1248 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-pull                                                                                                                                   
 724695 my_username  20   0 11808  616  612 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 724696 my_username  20   0 76316 1976 1972 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-remote-http                                                                                                                            
 880773 my_username  20   0  105m 1216 1212 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash                                                                                                                                       
 880782 my_username  20   0 11804  508  504 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 880783 my_username  20   0  105m 1252 1248 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-pull                                                                                                                                   
 880799 my_username  20   0 11808  616  612 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 880800 my_username  20   0 76316 1976 1972 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-remote-http                                                                                                                            
 894182 my_username  20   0  105m 1216 1212 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash                                                                                                                                       
 894191 my_username  20   0 11804  508  504 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 894193 my_username  20   0  105m 1252 1248 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-pull                                                                                                                                   
 894209 my_username  20   0 11808  620  612 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 894210 my_username  20   0 76316 1976 1972 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-remote-http                                                                                                                            
 994122 my_username  20   0  105m 1216 1212 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash                                                                                                                                       
 994131 my_username  20   0 11804  508  504 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 994132 my_username  20   0  105m 1252 1248 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-pull                                                                                                                                   
 994148 my_username  20   0 11808  616  612 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git                                                                                                                                        
 994149 my_username  20   0 76316 1976 1972 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 git-remote-http                                                                                                                            
1025934 my_username  20   0  339m  21m  17m S  0.0  0.0   0:00.75 lsphp                                                                                                                                      1044176 my_username  20   0  105m 1200 1196 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash
```

So as you can see most of the commands that are issuing this problem are the git commands that I am running on the server. Why are they not killed after some git operation? How to deal with this.

BTW, I have a limit of 50 processes and their number is constantly around **40** .

Thanks!

Comment: Are you executing the commands on a console and hitting ctrl + Z? just asking.